# R and DT - Can you add row subheadings and groups to a datatable?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

Is it possible to group rows and add sub headings to datatables using the `DT` package in `R`?

The bellow example is done using a example in Javascript (https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-dt-package-provide-multi-level-row-grouping-extensions/42377) question we can use `RowGroup`'s extension as follows

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          rownames = FALSE, 
          extensions = 'RowGroup', 
          options = list(rowGroup = list(dataSrc=c(4)),
                         columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(4)))
                         )
          )
```

[image]